# Confluent Platform on Docker needs restart after unwanted exit

Tags: docker, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I noticed that my Confluent Platform starts and immediately exits the services. Second run of `docker-compose up -d` established the environment. Where to start - if necesseary - fixing?

[image]

Comment: You probably don't have enough memory to run everything.

Comment: Do you mean not enough memory assigned to the dockerfile or not enough physical memory in my machine (RAM, CPU)

Comment: RAM. To run that whole compose file, requires at least 8GB. You could remove control center, ksql, and the rest proxy if you only want basic Kafka functions

Comment: I got 16GB of RAM so that might be issue with docker-compose file.

Comment: Okay then. You're going to have to show `docker-compose logs` of the various services that have exitted, probably starting with the broker